# Ionic not sending push notification

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, ngcordova

I'm using `ngCordova` `cordovaPushV5` and when I open the app I get the registration id just fine, but when I send the notification via POST request using Postman I do not get a notification on the device.

Here is the curl request I'm trying:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_API_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "tokens": ["dO-ocODiZSE:APA91bFTEvGakImDE3Jk-qhYyGwl86qq4R8bQuKikaQeyeYmDkaxWjMZTv47SmX0rvYUWLjpeG24LsQYIuE2KJA0I4U9Hq-2HyG9LuST3jn5SwLc1FTYQbyttIuKaGKHMDMTIaTdLyIx"],
    "profile": "trader_mobile",
    "notification": {
        "message": "Test"
    }
}' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "request_id": "5ac67cae-458e-4ff4-aa9a-ac86f4aff873",
    "version": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "status": 201
  },
  "data": {
    "app_id": "de12c106",
    "status": "open",
    "config": {
      "profile": "trader_mobile",
      "tokens": [
        "dO-ocODiZSE:APA91bFTEvGakImDE3Jk-qhYyGwl86qq4R8bQuKikaQeyeYmDkaxWjMZTv47SmX0rvYUWLjpeG24LsQYIuE2KJA0I4U9Hq-2HyG9LuST3jn5SwLc1FTYQbyttIuKaGKHMDMTIaTdLyIx"
      ],
      "notification": {
        "message": "Test"
      }
    },
    "uuid": "7efef50c-72bf-4e08-a176-4c28de8b2258",
    "state": "enqueued",
    "created": "2016-09-05T17:00:46.425695+00:00"
  }
}
```

But I still do not receive the notification on the device.

I've set up my gcm api key in my security profile in my Ionic Dashbaord, and uploaded my app with `ionic upload` and did `ionic io init`. I've tried every solution I could find, and I've tried just about every command in different orders. As well as removing the platform and adding it again. Still nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try sending notification from GCM instead of ionic-push

Comment: check for API Token and Security Profiles you have created.

Comment: Send another _GET_ to `https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications/<uuid>/messages` (`uuid` is the one from your _POST_ response) to receive more detailed data about what happened. If there is an error code, you can look up its description here: http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/docs/push-error-codes